# How can I fix this button script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I make this code work properly? It's old but all I could find. I'm trying to make a mania type of game and I need the 4 buttons to work properly. I've tried to change the code somehow and managed to get the button be pressed down, but the thing is that the button won't go back up, they just stay as they are, pressed down. If there are any people who've done something similar to this please help and even those who've not please help too. Thanks.

```cs
private SpriteRenderer theSR;
public Sprite defaultImage;
public Sprite pressedImage;

public KeyCode keyToPress;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start () =>
    theSR = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>(); 


// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(keyToPress))
      {
        theSR.sprite = pressedImage;
      }
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(keyToPress))
      {
        theSR.sprite = defaultImage;
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The two conditions are identical. You probably meant to negate the later to set the button's image do `defaultImage`, when the key "is not down".

```
if (! Input.GetKeyDown(keyToPress))
{
    theSR.sprite = defaultImage;
}
```

An if-else block whould be even neater:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(keyToPress))
{
    theSR.sprite = pressedImage;
}
else
{
    theSR.sprite = defaultImage;
}
```

Comment: If it solved your problem, please mark the answer as accepted.